# What are those faces at the beginning of DuckTales the Movie?

Tags: ducktales-the-movie

[image]

I was watching the opening sequence for [DuckTales the Movie: Treasure of the Lost Lamp (1990)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099472) and noticed the cliff face has 3 faces. Anyone know what/who are they?

[Update]
After the comments, I've gone through and tried to highlight what I see when I look at this (and any other faces I think people might be pointing out).
[image]

Comment: A quick search for keywords doesn't seem to be coming up with anything. Could just be our species' natural ability to find patterns in the seemingly random.

Comment: @MattD I would probably believe that if it wasn't Disney.  Disney loves doing this kind of stuff.

Comment: I can't see any faces.

Comment: I can see 4, with two vague potentials for a 5th... & a horse.

Comment: Okay, where are there any faces in that picture?

Comment: I see a hand holding a credit-card sized platelet in the front-right cloud. Do you want to know what kind of credit card that is as well?

Comment: @steelersquirrel They do, but we're talking about a Disney movie that's over 26 years old, and searches for "DuckTales movie rock faces" shows nothing. Even IMDb has no mention as to who these "faces" are supposed to be, if anyone/anything.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely explaination is that it is just an example of apophenia. Many people perceive faces in seemingly random places, such as in clouds.

Comment: I think pareidolia is a more relevant name of the phenomenon.

Comment: I think this is a fair guess, but Disney has done things like this a lot and it seems like they pause much too long on this scene for it to be a coincidence.

Comment: Creative people like to sneak this kind of easter egg in. In many disney movies you can see representations of mickey's ears. Search for 'pixar easter eggs' for an interesting example.